# How to load the i18 files from a remote location using http url?

Tags: spring, internationalization, translation, properties-file

My need is load the translation(i18) files from a remote location. I have tried the following code in java using spring framework, but the translation files are not getting loaded.

```
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource(); 
        messageSource.setBasename("file:http://www.test.com/test/messagesource");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(400);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        MessageSourceHolder.setMessageSource(messageSource);
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Here in remote location folder(test) contains the list of translation files like

- messagesource_en.properties
- messagesource_fr.properties
- messagesource_fi.properties .......

Is anything needs to be changed or corrected. ?

Comment: Remove `file:`....

Comment: Thanks working...